# Forcing Game to use Non-Default Audio Device Windows 10

Tags: windows-10, audio

In an effort to separate my game's audio from the desktop audio for streaming/recording purposes, I downloaded some software from [vb-audio](https://vb-audio.com/Cable/index.htm), including a virtual audio cable that I can dump an application to for OBS to pick up. Now, for standard applications like Firefox and Windows Media Player, this works great. However, quite a few games (20XX, Alien: Isolation and Doki Doki Literature Club are the ones I've tested so far), will ignore what I have set in the "App volume and device preferences" menu in the Windows 10 settings and instead will just default to the OS's default output upon startup. In the case of 20XX, it will refuse to use anything *but* the default, even if I attempt to change it in the Windows 10 settings while the game is running.

Is there a reliable way I can force an application to use a specific audio output, despite what it prefers?

Comment: It would be simpler to change the default audio device while running those games.

Comment: As in change the default device to my virtual cable, launch the game, and then change it back?

Comment: Yes, if possible.

Answer (score 0):

I'm having this exact issue. Setting the default to VB, launching, and then setting the default back to [headphones] DOES work but it's so clumsy. Using OBS I discovered that the audio STARTS on the VB device, but switches back to default.

I.e.: Skyrim set to VB, Default set to headphones, source in OBS monitoring VB will register audio for a couple seconds (the initial "Bethesda" splash and audio) and then switch to default.

I've been trying everything I can think of for 2 days to make this work neatly and have been unable to. Have yall found a better solution than virtual audio bait-and-switch?

Comment: This does not really answer the question. If you have a different question, you can ask it by clicking [Ask Question](https://superuser.com/questions/ask). To get notified when this question gets new answers, you can [follow this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/345661). Once you have enough [reputation](https://superuser.com/help/whats-reputation), you can also [add a bounty](https://superuser.com/help/privileges/set-bounties) to draw more attention to this question. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/1157921)

Answer (score 0):

You can try to automate the trick by [SoundVolumeView](https://www.nirsoft.net/utils/sound_volume_view.html).

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).